# How to set the timezone to mat-date-picker to highlight the today indicator according to provided Timezone

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I have in-app timezone functionality. in Angular mat date-picker the circle that highlights the today day in a circle is from the system timezone I want that circle to be from provided timezone